Must I label percussion "switches" in orchestral part where clefs make it obvious?
Title pretty much says it, but here goes.  I'm formatting instrumental parts for a chamber work that will be played by orchestra musicians (professional).  One player will be assigned to timpani and tubular bells.  Is it strictly necessary to indicate where the player should switch between?  As far as I have ever seen, timpani is only ever printed in bass clef and t.b. in treble.
Assuming that the requirements are clearly spelled out on the part and in the score, is this clear?  We are playing A-D on tubular bells, and then rolling on the timpani 5 bars later.


It may or may not be necessary, but what would be easier for the player?

Well, that is the million dollar question.   Less likely to miss a clef change and play the wrong instrument on the one hand, but with the vertical space gained by not marking the switches, fewer page turns in a fast piece.

The motivation — fewer page turns — should be part of the main post rather than a comment. Also, why can't the part be formatted to make page turns easier?

In a hand-written score it would be easy to fit "t.b." or "timp." above the staff and after the "5" in the section you have shown,  without changing the positioning of the staves or any of the notes on them. Some players might pencil the indications anyway. Why not save them the trouble, or does your software not allow you to do it?

What’s the downside to labeling the instrument changes?

Your sample image seems to show plenty of white space where you can fit labels (depending on the software's capabilities.)

Put them in.  It costs you nothing, in layout space or anything else.
Be aware that in the orchestral world the timpanist doesn't 'double', he just plays the timps.  A union thing rather than a practical one.

There are some pieces that require eight timpani drums instead of the usual four. Especially since the timpanist needs to tune the timpani before the piece and sometimes even during the piece, no way is the timpanist switching instruments midway through.

Yes to union rules.  This part will be played my an orchestra musician, but not in an orchestra setting.  So the director has made these arrangements.  Also it's only 2 timpani drums in the setup.  Good points alll

@Dekkadeci  Yes, there are pieces that keep the timpanist busy with  re-tunings.  And pieces that require two timpanists.  And theatre percussionists who include one or two kettles in an eclectic battery of things to hit!  But the symphonic union man doesn't restrict himself because he CAN'T get to other instruments, but because he's engaged to play timpani, period.
Recently the English National Opera did a production of My Fair Lady.   There's a percussion book, with a few notes for timp.   They engaged both players.  Similarly for the string bass/tuba (a common Broadway 'double) book.
